# cryptsetup failed with code 22 invalid argument

Tags: debian, encryption, luks, cryptsetup, dm-crypt

[image]

I have read

- [`cryptsetup luksOpen <device> <name>` fails to set up the specified name mapping](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/417135/cryptsetup-luksopen-device-name-fails-to-set-up-the-specified-name-mapping)
- https://www.saout.de/pipermail/dm-crypt/2014-August/004272.html

And tried

```
cryptsetup open --type luks <device> <dmname> --key-file /root/luks.key
```

still getting error 22

```
cryptsetup luksFormat <device> --key-file /root/luks.key -q
```

output command successful.

Followed steps here:
https://gist.github.com/huyanhvn/1109822a989914ecb730383fa0f9cfad

Created key with

```
openssl genrsa -out /root/luks.key 4096
chmod 400 /root/luks.key
```

[image]

```
$ sudo dmsetup targets
striped          v1.6.1
linear           v1.3.1
error            v1.5.1
```

---

**Edit 1**

Realised dm_crypt is not loaded, so did

```
$ modprobe dm_crypt
```

To check

```
$ lsmod | grep -i dm_mod
$ which cryptsetup
```

[image]

Also checked

```
$ blkid /dev/data
/dev/data: UUID="xxxxxxxxxxxx" TYPE="crypto_LUKS"
```

---

**Edit 2**

More missing module:

```
modprobe aes_generic
modprobe xts
```

Kernel

```
$ uname -r
4.9.0-12-amd64
```

OS is Debian Stretch

And it's an Azure provided image, I'm not sure if they have patched anything related to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a naming conflict, I already have `/dev/mapper/data` due to the previous testing, so have to test it with another name.

```
cryptsetup open --type luks /dev/data new_name  # 1st time sucess
cryptsetup open --type luks /dev/data new_name  # 2nd time fail
```